# How to close "add ... as default mailto link application" popup in the browser using java Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am developing Selenium automation application and this popup shifts the html down in browser window, making it inconvinient to click.[image]

Using Firefox.

Is it possible to close it or not allow its creation in the first place?
Didnt find any preferences which would allow me to do that.

Thanks for any help.

Added my browser initialization method

```
    public static RemoteWebDriver init(String ua)
{
    String link="https://www.google.com/";
    String localDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",localDir+"\\lib\\geckodriver-v0.28.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    FirefoxOptions opts = new FirefoxOptions();
    opts.addArguments("incognito");
    opts.setHeadless(false);
    opts.addPreference("permissions.default.desktop-notification", 2);
    opts.addPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
    opts.addPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en-US, en");
    opts.addPreference("general.useragent.override",ua);
    opts.addPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
    RemoteWebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(opts);
    driver.get(link);
    saveSession(driver);
    lastdriver=driver;
    act=new Actions(lastdriver);
    
    return driver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try use incognito mode in your browser initialization?

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArgument("incognito");

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

This is a c# way but might be something similar to java.

Comment: I have tried after your proposal. It still appears. Added my init method above